# PHP - existing string value not found in $_SESSION array

Tags: php, mysql

I asked this question before, but it got no responses, so I deleted the last question, and simplified/clarified the question, and am reposting

---

I have a comics site... I'm working on a SO-style tagging system. A user can select 1 or many tags which will display all associated comics.

To remember the user selections, I'm storing them in a $_SESSION array.

**The issue** I'm having is that one of the strings, 'business', being stored in the $_SESSION['tagnames'] array after it is chosen by the user is not being found in the array...

The way it's supposed to work is a user selects a tag, and to deselect it, they click it again... so I check if the string is in the $_SESSION... if it is, unset it... here is a snippet:

```
    //var_dump shows these are both set fine when a user clicks on the tag they want
    $tagid = (isset($_GET['tagid']) ? ($_GET['tagid']) : null); 
    $tagname = (isset($_GET['tagname']) ? ($_GET['tagname']) : null); 

    ...

//Tag IDS are added and removed without issue:
    //if tag id exists in $_SESSION['tags'] array, remove it 

    if ($key = array_search($tagid, $_SESSION['tagids'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['tagids'][$key]);
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['tagids'][] = $tagid;
    }

    ...

//but one of the tag names, 'business', is not being removed... and is actually added again even when I press F5 to refresh

    if ($key =  array_search($tagname, $_SESSION['tagname'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['tagname'][$key]);
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['tagname'][] = $tagname;
    }
```

This is a `var_dump` of the sql statement: It correctly shows the query being changed based on which tag id is selected.

[image]

Here's a `var_dump` of the `$_SESSION['tagname']`... you can see that it recognizes when tags 2 and 3 (differences and similarities) have already been added (I used `array_search()` to check), but it doesn't find tagid 1, 'business', even though it's clearly been added several times.

[image]

**Here's the function that returns the selected tag names to the user:**

```
function getSelectedTags() {

 global $tagid, $tagname;

    if ($key =  array_search($tagname, $_SESSION['tagname'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['tagname'][$key]);
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['tagname'][] = $tagname;
    }

    var_dump($_SESSION['tagname']);

    foreach ($_SESSION['tagname'] as $tagname) { 
        echo '<span class="tags">' . $tagname . '</span>';
    }
}
```

Any thoughts why tagname 'business' is the only thing causing an issue?

Even after I destroy the session, pressing F5 to refresh will automatically put tagname 'business' into the `$_SESSION['tagname'] array.`

---

EDIT: More comprehensive code:

**Homepage.php:** user clicks on returned tags from getDBTags() to add a tag to the $_SESSION array on imageDisplay.php

```
<h5>Tags</h5>
<?php echo getDBTags(); ?>
<br/>
<p>Your tags:</p>
<?php echo getSelectedTags(); ?>
```

**imageDisplay.php:** responsible for handling how images are filtered and displayed...

*getDBTags()* returns tag choices from the database so users can click on them:

```
function getDBTags() {
include 'dbconnect.php';

global $cat;

$sql = "SELECT tagid, tagname FROM tags";

$query = $mysqli->query($sql);

while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<span class="tags"><a href=".?action=homepage&cat='.$cat.'&tagid='.$row['tagid'].'&tagname='.$row['tagname'].'">'.$row['tagname'].'</a></span>';
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
}
```

*getFilters()* decides how images should be filtered by having a dynamic query, then sends the query to pagination(), which displays filtered images on pages.

```
function getFilters() {
include 'dbconnect.php';

global $cat, $site, $table, $tagid;

$order = " ORDER BY date DESC";

//if tag id exists in $_SESSION['tags'] array, remove it 
if ($key = array_search($tagid, $_SESSION['tagids'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['tagids'][$key]);
}
//if it doesn't, add it
else {
    $_SESSION['tagids'][] = $tagid;
}
//var_dump($_SESSION['tagids']);

if ($cat != null) $catquery = " AND catidFK = $cat";
else $catquery = null;

$sql = 
 "SELECT c.*, t.* 
 FROM comics c 
 INNER JOIN comictags ct ON (c.id = ct.comicID)
 INNER JOIN tags t ON (t.tagid = ct.tagID)
 WHERE ct.tagID IN ('" . implode(', ', $_SESSION['tagids']). "')
". $catquery ." " . $order;

if (!$mysqli->query($sql)) printf("<br /><b>Error:</b> %s\n", $mysqli->error); 

$query = $mysqli->query($sql);

var_dump($sql);
mysqli_close($mysqli);

return $query;
}
```

*getSelectedTags()* returns the selected tag title back to the user so they can see what they've chosen. If they click on a tag again (returned from *getDBTags()* above), it will remove the tag from $_SESSION['tagname']. This is the problem area:

```
function getSelectedTags() {

global $tagid, $tagname;
if ($key =  array_search($tagname, $_SESSION['tagname'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['tagname'][$key]);
}
else {
    $_SESSION['tagname'][] = $tagname;
}
//var_dump($key =  array_search($tagname, $_SESSION['tagname']));
var_dump($_SESSION['tagname']);

foreach ($_SESSION['tagname'] as $tagname) { 
    echo '<span class="tags">' . $tagname . '</span>';
}

}
```

Comment: why do you unset the variable if it is found?

Comment: @MarshallHouse because if a user clicks on the same tag again, it will check if it already exists... if it does, it will remove it. This is my way of allowing users to remove tags they don't want

Comment: ah, my bad. This seems to be something to do with global variables. which are hated because of the confusion they cause. Give me a bit.

Comment: @MarshallHouse No prob dude, thanks for the time. Btw, yeah... globals are horrible in PHP... why do they need to be explicitly stated all the time?

Comment: @MarshallHouse let me know if you need to see the full code

Comment: i reckon it might be ($key =  array_search($tagname, $_SESSION['tagname']))  i think it is returning 0 . try changing it to  ( ($key =  array_search($tagname, $_SESSION['tagname']) ) !== false )

Comment: There is always a way to NOT use globals. They are 100% unnecessary. Much better to pass your variables around or better yet, learn OOP.

Comment: @MarshallHouse Yeah, after I release ver 2 of my site, I'll recode it all OOP.

Comment: @marabutt +1 - the `if ($key...` would evaluate to false if the key were 0.

Comment: @marabutt You're on to something, when clicking on 'business' tag, `var_dump($key =  array_search($tagname, $_SESSION['tagname']));` always evaluates to `int 0`, whereas the other two tags evaluate to the correct place in the array, or false if it is unset (which is correct).

Comment: @marabutt setting that to !== false now prevents additional values from being added to `$_SESSION['tagname']`, but the var_dump of the $sql still shows the tag being added: `"...WHERE ct.tagID IN ('2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2')`

Comment: can you post more code?

Comment: destroy the session then start again. see if the problem recurs.

Comment: @marabutt I tried that and it didn't work (I put `session_destroy();` at the top right under `session_start();`) Updated and added all relevant code above

Comment: Are you using ob_start() and session_start() on the code pages

Comment: @Vineet1982 session_start()

Comment: from getting messed up use code working put session_start(); on every page so that the pages are linked to single session only

Comment: @Vineet1982 putting `session_start();` on homepage.php, then again on paging.php which is included in homepage.php, produces this error: "A session had already been started"

Comment: If the output has started then you cannot re-set the session_start again as if possible to project full access to code would give more precise view to problem as pieces of code is not serving purpose

Comment: you can email me the codes and sample db to vineetgupta22@gmail.com to look into problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25291/discussion-between-growler-and-vineet1982)

Comment: @marabutt any more thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three issues which stand out (well two stand out, one is very subtle).

#### 1. Open only one DB connection and leave it:

First, instead of opening and closing the connection in `$mysqli` in your functions, do it once at the start of the script and leave it open.  You'll need to modify your functions to accept `$mysqli` as a parameter (preferred) or access it via `global $mysqli;` (not preferred).  There is no need to call `mysqli_close()`, as that is done implicitly.

In your `getFilters()` function, you are actually closing the MySQLi resource `$mysqli` and then attempting to `return $query;` where `$query` is a result resource. Doing that will render the result resource useless.

```
// Pass $mysqli as a parameter
function getFilters($mysqli) {
  //...
  // Do alll your stuff...
  // And do not call mysqli_close()!
  return $query
}
```

#### 2. Use strict comparison and test for `FALSE` with `array_search()`:

When using `array_search()`, if your result is the first element in the array at key `[0]`, that will be regarded by a surrounding `if ()` condition as a falsy return rather than the positive result it should be. For that reason, a tag at position `[0]` will get repeatedly added rather than removed.  This will need to be fixed in a couple of places...

```
// First get the key, which is an int or FALSE
$key = array_search($tagid, $_SESSION['tagids']);
// Unset if it is FALSE by strict comparison
if ($key !== FALSE) { 
  unset($_SESSION['tagids'][$key]); 
} 
else {
   $_SESSION['tagids'][] = $tagid;
}
```

#### 3. Global variable `$tagname` is ruined by a `foreach`:

You have accessed the global `$tagname` in `getSelectedTags()`.  But in that function you have a `foreach` loop which does :

```
foreach ($_SESSION['tagname'] as $tagname)
```

When using `$tagname` as the loop's variable there, it is actually overwriting the global `$tagname` on each iteration.  You need to change that to a different value, or whenever you call `getSelectedTags()`, `$tagname` the global will become whatever the last tag in `$_SESSION['tagname']` had been, without exception.

```
// use a different varname in the loop
foreach ($_SESSION['tagname'] as $tn) {
  // Also calling htmlspecialchars to escape here. Do this in any variable to HTML output...
  echo '<span class="tags">' . htmlspecialchars($tn) . '</span>';
}
```